# python count size specific type file txt in a directory

Tags: python, file, io, size

In my folder, there are two types of files: `html` and `txt`. 
I want to know the total size of the `txt` files.

I found this code, but how do I apply it for my needs?

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
size = 0
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    size += sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files)
    count += len(files)
print count, size
```

Comment: For name in files if name in '.txt' - add this at the end. But os path also has a native command, ehich I cannot recall. I can have a look when I'm at computer .)

Comment: .endswith is what you need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can qualify which files by adding an `if` to the comprehensions like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    size += sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files if name.endswith('.txt'))
    count += sum(1 for name in files if name.endswith('.txt'))
print count, size
```

Comment: works for the size, but your third line shows red line on "name": unresolved reference name. NameError: global name 'name' is not defined. Do I need to make name='' ?

Comment: ok, it was 1 for _ in files. I replaced _ as name. Then works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

better use glob (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) instead of os to find your files. that makes it imho more readable.

```
import glob
import os

path = '/tmp'
files = glob.glob(path + "/**/*.txt")
total_size = 0
for file in files:
    total_size += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, file))
print len(files), total_size
```